# Drivers for my laptop

Tags: 12.04

Now I am thinking of completely removing my windows 7 and switching over to Ubuntu.
I have a query that whether I will have to install drivers for my laptop(eg.Sound,wireless,lan etc). I use a lenovo G570 laptop. Core i5 second generation. 
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever tried to boot a live Ubuntu? There you can play around with it and find out what's working and what not. If you encounter any problems (i.e. graphical glitches, slow internet, bluetooth not working), search for the hardware piece (get the name from Windows Device Manager) together with "Ubuntu driver".
But in very few cases it's necessary to install additional drivers.

Comment: I have installed wubi. I didn't find any problem as such.

Comment: I HAVE NOT USED IT, but doesn't it just install it inside the Windows system? Also, this may not work for the latest Ubuntu release - 13.10 "Saucy Salamander" - [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_(Ubuntu_installer)). I would probably recommend a full install, or make a Dual-Boot system (difficult (probably - ain't tried it), but useful for compatibility)

Comment: That's what I mean with "Live system". Create a installation media (DVD/USB-Stick) and boot from it. There you have the option to try it.

Comment: DO NOT USE WUBI. It's slow, it's broken, it's deprecated and discontinued.

Comment: Thanks guys... will first try with live cd and then head with complete installation :)

Comment: Sorry, me again. Checked with Ubuntu 13.10, and the card reader works brilliantly .... ?

Answer (score 1):

NO ,you will not have to download drivers(*sound,wireless.LAN*) for **Lenovo G570** to run ubuntu.But You must need to download and install graphics drivers.

Comment: I didn't - mine worked out the box, no fiddling required, even though the speakers are _also_ Realtek. The wifi card can vary by supplier, but I have a Broadcom BCM4313 802.11bgn, which can vary with Bluetooth, but the wireless works a treat, and receives signals from 20m plus. The ethernet connection also works straight away.

Answer (score 1):

Reply from my Lenovo G570 laptop, also with a Dual-Core i5, :-).

Both Fedora and Ubuntu work very well on it, and I have had next to no problems - apart from trying to add a Radeon Graphics Card, and the SD card port does not work *at all* :-( - (b***dy Realtek drivers).

Also, the hyper-threaded processor works a treat.

N.B - Here is a tip, when installing, turn the wireless switch on (if your laptop has one), as then, when the installer detects what drivers are required, its somehow seems to work better. If you cannot find it, it should be below the touchpad on the left.

---

**UPDATE**

Checked with Ubuntu 13.10, and the card reader works brilliantly .... ? [image: puzzled]

Comment: What the heck... The SD Card Port doesn't work... Any solution for it?

Comment: Depends on your card reader model. Mine is a annoying 'Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller', which, when I last checked, did not have any drivers available. If you found the make and model of yours, you could check yourself.

Comment: N.B. This says no: [http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=15&PFid=25&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2](http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=15&PFid=25&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2)